# How do I add dependency to my Test in RobotFramework, So that if Test B is dependent on Test A. Executing Test B should Trigger Test A automatically?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, testing, robotframework

I need to add a condition in my test suite, where test B is dependent on test A.

```
*** Settings ***
Library             DependencyLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
test A
    ## Test case A
test B
    Depends On Test     test A
    ## Test Case B
```

But when I am executing only test B, it is failing with

```
Dependency not met: test case 'test A' not found.
```

Is there a way to trigger test A automatically when test B is called.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to start a Test within another testcase. (https://groups.google.com/g/robotframework-users/c/EkVGikv6Eks)

What you could do is do whatever u want to do in Test A, in a keyword. Lets call it Keyword A for example.

```
Keyword A
    ## Here you do whatever you wanted to do in Test A
```

Now what you could do in Test B is run Keyword A and return the status. Then use a if-else statement to execute or fail Test B like this:

```
Test B
    ${status}    Run Keyword And Return Status    Keyword A
    IF    "${status}" == "True"
        ## Here you do whatever you wanted to do in Test B
    ELSE
        Fail
    END
```

Comment: Thanks Ruben. Keyword approach doesn’t work for my use case.